# How do I create a unique code (in SQL) created by the system which includes date and hour of arrival + 3 letter code?

Tags: sql, mysql

For a final project I was sent to create an airport webpage in which for each fly, the system on its own (automatically) creates a unique code in which it must include its own:

- Date Time of Arrival
- Hour of arrival
- 3 varchar code for the Destiny

It is supposed to look something like this:

***yyyyMMddHHmmAer (ex: 202401202050MVD)***

I can`t seem to understand if I do this directly on the tables or if in a stored procedure

[This is my table for the flies. I have yet to create the stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilCew.png)

Comment: you would use a function that return a varchar

Comment: Use `DATE_FORMAT()` to format a DATETIME, and `CONCAT()` to concatenate strings.

Comment: Your table has dates, but I don't see the time of arrival.

Comment: are you supposed to add this code to all existing rows?  or calculate a value for a new row that is being inserted?

Comment: It is supposed to be calculated automatically  when a Client buys a ticket for a fly

Answer (score 1):

Use generated column:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  arrival_datetime DATETIME,
  destiny_code CHAR(3),
  unique_code CHAR(15) AS (CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(arrival_datetime, '%Y%m%d%H%i'), 
                                  destiny_code)) VIRTUAL INVISIBLE
  );
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2024-01-20 20:50:23', 'MVD');
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| arrival_datetime | destiny_code |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-20 20:50:23 | MVD |

```
SELECT *, unique_code FROM test;
```

| arrival_datetime | destiny_code | unique_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-20 20:50:23 | MVD | 202401202050MVD |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sG_0amWA)

INVISIBLE column property allows you do not edit existing SQL code of data modifying queries, but you must specify it explicitly when you need its value.